# UnityEngine.Object does not contain a definition for GetComponent

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

I got below error in Unity3D iOS game.

```
Assets/Scripts/Block/BlockMaker.cs(24,55): error CS1061: Type `UnityEngine.Object' does not contain a definition for `GetComponent' and no extension method `GetComponent' of type `UnityEngine.Object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[image]

Here is Code:

```
Block block = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < listBlocks.Count; ++i)
        {
            if (listBlocks[i].GetComponent<Block>().type == type) {
                block =  Instantiate(listBlocks[i]).GetComponent<NormalBlock>(); // Error for this line
            }
        }
```

Here is screenshot
[image]

[image]

How to Fix this problem? Already googled..none helped me to fix.

Comment: What type if listBlocks?

Comment: @Programmer public List<GameObject> listBlocks;

Comment: Does the script `Block` inherit from MonoBehavior? Also, the script, you have that code inside, does it inherit from `MonoBehavior`? If you don't mind, what's your Unity version?

Comment: yes its inherit from MonoBehaviour. Unity version 4.6.9

Comment: @Programmer here is full class screenshot : https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XCfB.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to cast what `Instantiate` returns which is an `Object`. Check the documentation : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

```
block = ( Instantiate(listBlocks[i]) as GameObject).GetComponent<NormalBlock>();
```

Comment: This fixed problem. Thanks a lots

Answer (score 3):

In the old version of Unity, calling the `Instantiate` function, will try to call [`Object.Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) which returns an `Object`.

In the latest version of Unity, calling `Instantiate` will call `GameObject.Instantiate` which returns a `GameObject` so you don't even need to cast it to a GameObject. This code was able to compile with *5.6* version but not with your version *4.6.9*.

Use:

```
block = GameObject.Instantiate(listBlocks[i]).GetComponent<NormalBlock>();
```

OR cast it to a `GameObject` as mentioned in Hellium's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44228299/3785314).

```
GameObject obj = Instantiate(listBlocks[i]) as GameObject;
block = obj.GetComponent<NormalBlock>();
```

Comment: not fixed in 4.6.9 bro, above answer from Hellium fixed problem. Thanks for your support

Comment: It's not a problem and it's not fixed. I said it works in 5.6 not 4.6.9 as you mentioned above.  More functions were added in the latest version of Unity so that you don't need to cast it. Please read the answer again.